# SQL query to join three tabels

Tags: mysql, sql

I have done this in the far past but now I just can't figure it out.

I have three tables with one serving as reference or lookup table to avoid duplication of data. Below are the basic structure: Table Name: `Column1`, `Column2` ...

```
Tasks : ID , Description
Tags : ID , TagID , TaskID
TagNames : ID , Title
```

I want to create a query that would return all records of table 3 but instead of IDs (numbers) to get the corresponding title and description.

This is one of the queries I tried

```
SELECT Tasks.Description, TagNames.Title 
FROM (Tags INNER JOIN Tasks ON Tags.TaskID = Tasks.ID) 
INNER JOIN TagNames ON TagNames.ID = Tags.TagID
```

End Result:

```
"Task 1", "Home":
"Task 1", "PC":
"Task 2", "Home":
```

I have tried and tried but I always get a "Type mismatch in expression" or some such

I am certain its something super simple but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT Tasks.Description, TagNames.Title 
 FROM Tags tags, Tasks tasks,TagNames tagNames
 WHERE tags.TaskID = tasks.ID AND
 tagNames.ID = tags.TagID
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from your first inner join?

```
SELECT 
Tasks.Description, 
TagNames.Title 
FROM Tags 
INNER JOIN Tasks ON Tags.TaskID = Tasks.ID
INNER JOIN TagNames ON TagNames.ID = Tags.TagID
```

Comment: When ran in Access 2018 the following error appears: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TAgs.TaskID = Tasks.ID INNER JOIN TagNames ON TagNames.ID = Tags.Tagl'. Which makes me think there needs to be something before the second "INNER JOIN"